# JS fires twice confirm-box onchange MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have a problem, on the Telerik dropdownlist i have a function onchange selection. This function save a value with ajax call if an item from list is selected. If selection is not OK will show a confirm box, if the user press OK will be redirected on another page. If press Cancel need to populate a field with empty string.
The problem is: if the user press CANCEL button, the confirm-box fires twice...I tried to put return false after $('#Assessment').val(''); but does not work..
Any solutions please?

**DropDownlist:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
     .Name("Assessment").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:center", onchange = "saveAssessment()" })
        .OptionLabel("Select an assessment")
        .DataTextField("DisplayName")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .Value("DisplayName")
```

**JS Function**

```
function saveAssessment() {
     var assessmentId = $('#Assessment').val();
     var grid = $('#_gridProjectCheckList').data('kendoGrid');
     var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
     var ciId = selectedItem.Id;
     var ciText = $("#Assessment").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
     if (assessmentId !== null && (ciText === 'Ok' || ciText === 'NotApplicable')) {
         $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
         $.ajax({
             url: 'UpdateProjectCheckItemAssessment',
             type: "POST",
             data: { assessmentId: assessmentId, id: ciId },
             success: function (response) {
                 $('#Assessment').val(response.assessmentVal);
                 $('#_gridProjectCheckList').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
             }
         });
     }
     else {
         var msgRedir = confirm("You will be redirected to Assessment Page");
         if (msgRedir) {
             window.location.href = 'UpdateProjectCheckItem' + '/' + selectedItem.Id;
         }
             $('#Assessment').val('');
     }
 }
```